# JQuery Multi-Page control the first page displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm  using JQuery Mobile's recommended multi-page approach to separate out pages.  What I don't know (I'm a bit of JQuery and Javascipt noob)  is how to control which page loads first.

I want to run a check to local storage for the user's credentials, which I can do, if they exist they can use the web app as usual, if not I want to navigate them to the login page.  How can I do this before the first page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call your function during onload of your page.Hope this helps.
Check out this fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay/HPy3a/21/

Answer (score 0):

you can put your logic in
    $("#firstpage").live("pageshow",function(){
      // redirect user }
where firstpage is the id of the first subpage located in .html file